# Why can't I ExecuteNonQuery()?

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, combobox

This is my code:

```
   private void loadlist()
   {
      comboBox1.Items.Clear();
      cn.Open();
      cmd.CommandText = "Select * from info";
      dr = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
      if (dr.HasRows)
      {
         while (dr.Read())
         {
            comboBox1.Items.Add(dr[0].ToString());
         }
         cn.Close();
      }
    }
```

The error occurs on this line:

```
dr = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I am using `System.Data.SqlClient;`

and:

```
SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(@"//HERE IS MY STRING CONNECTION");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
SqlDataReader dr;
```

Comment: Well, it _is_ a query. Why would you use that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is the correct code for a `SqlDataReader`:

```
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

`ExecuteNonQuery()` is only used for (surprise, surprise) things that are **not** queries, i.e. SQL commands that don't return data (like UPDATE and DELETE).

You will also need to assign the connection to the command.

```
cmd.Connection = cn;
cn.Open();
```

You should also remember to close both the reader and the connection when you're done. Or use a `using` block

Comment: it told me ExecuteReader: Connection property has not been initialized.

Comment: You need to open the connection and assign it to the command. See the edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

ExecuteNonQuery Executes a Transact-SQL statement against the connection and returns the number of rows affected, such as UPDATE, INSERT, or DELETE See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx)

You can use

```
ExecuteReader();
```

More doc on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kcbe65k.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You should use `SqlDataReader` and `ExecuteReader` method to read datarows from a select statement. Example:

```
private static void ReadOrderData(string connectionString)
{
    string queryString =
        "SELECT OrderID, CustomerID FROM dbo.Orders;";

    using (SqlConnection connection =
               new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand command =
            new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
        connection.Open();

        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        // Call Read before accessing data.
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}, {1}",
                reader[0], reader[1]));
        }

        // Call Close when done reading.
        reader.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

***ExecuteNonQuery***

ExecuteNonQuery method will return number of rows effected with INSERT, DELETE or UPDATE operations. This ExecuteNonQuery method will be used only for insert, update and delete, Create, and SET statements.

***ExecuteScalar***

Execute Scalar will return single row single column value i.e. single value, on execution of SQL Query or Stored procedure using command object. It’s very fast to retrieve single values from database.

***ExecuteReader***

Execute Reader will be used to return the set of rows, on execution of SQL Query or Stored procedure using command object. This one is forward only retrieval of records and it is used to read the table values from first to last.

In your case `dr = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`

`dr` is `IdataReader(DataReader)` so you cant use `ExecuteNonQuery`..... instead of this one use `ExecuteReader`

Answer (score 0):

use `cmd.ExecuteReader()` instead of `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code and everything will be fine.

```
private void loadlist()
{
  comboBox1.Items.Clear();
  cn.Open();
  cmd.CommandText = "Select * from info";
  dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()

     while (dr.Read())
     {
        comboBox1.Items.Add(dr.GetString(0));
     }
  cn.Close();

}
```